# Redis + Node.js -- Loop over set members

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Here's where I'm adding the set `users`. Each `user` has a `userID` and a `socketID`:

```
 socket.on('login', function(userID){
      console.log('io.sockets.on -- socket.on -- userID: ' + userID);
      console.log('socket.id = ' + socket.id);

      var user = userID;

      // add first user
      redis.sadd("users", user);
      redis.hmset(user, "socketID", socket.id, "userID", userID);  
    });
```

Here's where I'm trying to retrieve all `users` in the set and loop over them:

```
    // Get the list of online users and show Presence
    redis.smembers("users", function(err,results) {

        var onlineUsers = results;

        console.log("onlineUsers = " + onlineUsers);

        for (var onlineUser in onlineUsers) {

            console.log("onlineUser = " + onlineUser);

            var userID = redis.hget(onlineUser,"userID", function(err,reply) {
                console.log("onlineUser hget: " + reply);
                data = JSON.parse(reply);
                console.log("data: " +data);

            });       
    });
```

And here are the logs:

```
16:41:15 web.1  | onlineUsers = user:AuY0Uopq6X,user:YbgtwQs8Vt
16:41:16 web.1  | onlineUser = 0
16:41:16 web.1  | onlineUser = 1
16:41:16 web.1  | onlineUser hget: null
16:41:16 web.1  | data: null
16:41:16 web.1  | onlineUser hget: null
16:41:16 web.1  | data: null
```

I'm very confused by node-redis and how to simply get the `userID`s. I know they're there because `onlineUsers` contains them, but then I'm doing something wrong in the iteration!

---

EDIT

I tried using `redis-cli` and the key is there:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS users
1) "user:AuY0Uopq6X"
2) "user:YbgtwQs8Vt"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HKEYS "user:AuY0Uopq6X"
1) "socketID"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Still no luck getting them with the above code.

---

EDIT - SOLVED

I had issues on how I was SETTING AND GETTING the data. I wasn't setting the "user hash" on the right key for "users set". Here's the correct version:

```
  var user = userID;

  // add first user
  redis.sadd("users", user);
  redis.hmset("users:"+user, "socketID", socket.id, "userID", userID);
```

However, I also needed to implement Philippe T's change when GETTING the user hash.

Comment: have you check what is the  err value in the callback of your hget command?

Comment: 16:56:26 web.1  | error: null

Comment: All null! I'm suspecting `for (var onlineUser in onlineUsers)` doesn't give me an object for `onlineUser`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you getting by index of "users" elements instead of values, try this :

```
 // Get the list of online users and show Presence
redis.smembers("users", function(err,results) {

    var onlineUsers = results;

    console.log("onlineUsers = " + onlineUsers);

    for (var i in onlineUsers) {

        console.log("onlineUser = " + i);
        console.log("onlineUser = " + onlineUsers[i]);


        var userID = redis.hget(onlineUsers[i],"userID", function(err,reply) {
            console.log("onlineUser hget: " + reply);
            data = JSON.parse(reply);
            console.log("data: " +data);

        });       
});
```

Comment: OK. That's confusing. What is `results`? Isn't it just an array of individual `users`? You're getting the index in the `for` loop, but then when you pass `onlineUsers[i]` to hget you're eventually passing the same this as when I passed `onlineUser`, right?

Comment: That being said, I did get a value from `hget` when I used your code... I'm just trying to understand why it's different.

Comment: when you iter in your "for in" statement , you have index of array. So to retreive from the name you have to get value from the array and use it on the hget. In you code i = onlineuser = index of element

Comment: how would you do this if you had multi
client.multi()...iterate and all elements...client.execute()